# How to consume REST api in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: rest, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have made a REST API and I want to use it using my Xamarin.iOS application.
Basically I want to call the API from my Xamarin application by sending some arguments to one of my API's function.

I tried the resources available at Xamarin's official website, but I a newbie so I cannot understand how it was done.
The REST API is hosted locally by the network I am using. It is not hosted at a static IP. 
Kindly guide me.

Comment: this is a very broad topic.  Xamarin has a good overview here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/consuming/rest/.  If you have trouble following that it would be helpful if you asked a specific question about the part(s) you don't understand.

Comment: Use RestSharp plug in, you can get it form Xamarin plugin store. I use it personally and does the job great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a fancy plugin if you just want to hit Web Endpoints. I simply use the basic WebRequest API.

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(YOUR_URL_HERE);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/JSON";
request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseComplete, request);
```

... and then your response method can be something along the lines of...

```
protected void ResponseComplete(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        var request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Completed query: " + request.RequestUri);
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Debug.WriteLine("Query Result: " + result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... and if you need to post data you can add `request.BeginGetRequestStream(PostData, request);` before `request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseComplete, request);` and make your GetRequestStream handling method something along the lines of...

```
protected void PostData(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
    if (request != null)
    {
        using (var postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DATA_TO_POST);
            Debug.WriteLine("Posting data: " + json);
            var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit), you can install it as a NuGet package. Its pritty simple to use.

> Refit allows us to define an interface that describes the API that we're calling, and the Refit framework handles making the call to the service and deserializing the return.

Have a look at this great blog post on how to set it up and other packages that might help you out. http://arteksoftware.com/resilient-network-services-with-xamarin/

I have used RestSharp before but Refit is alot easier to get running.